# Reset a repeating Coroutine delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm using a Coroutine to set up a repeating delay as follows.

In my Awake I have

```
StartCoroutine(RandomMove());
```

And then further down

```
IEnumerator RandomMove()
    {
       while (true)
        {
            // print(Time.time);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(foo);
            // print(Time.time);
        }

    }
```

where 'foo' is a random float value that I change with every iteration.
Lets say foo is 10 seconds and part way thru the delay I need to reset the delay so it starts 'counting down' from 10 again.

How would I accomplish this? Should I use a Timer instead?

Comment: Can you provide another example? It's not super clear to me what you're trying to accomplish. If you are trying to "reset" the delay before `foo` time has expired, you would probably need to Stop and Start the coroutine again. Or are you just trying to figure out how to have a new variable each iteration?

Answer (score 5):

I don't like either of the two existing answers. Here's what I'd do:

## Kill and Restart the coroutine:

We'll start with this part of the killer_mech's answer:

```
Coroutine myCoroutine;
void Awake() {
    myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RandomMove());
}
```

But we're going to handle the rest differently. killer_mech never *did* anything with the reference, other than to keep ovewriting it.

Here's what we're doing instead:

```
public void resetRandomMove() {
    StopCoroutine(myCoroutine);
    myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RandomMove());
}
```

Call this any time you need to reset it.

Comment: Nice! And to call coroutine the first time after the game's been running (not in Awake), can call `resetRandomMove` and change the first line to: `if (myCoroutine != null) { StopCoroutine(myCoroutine); }`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you first store Coroutine in a variable.

```
Coroutine myCoroutine;
void Awake()
{
 myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RandomMove());
}
```

and change the coroutine function as

```
IEnumerator RandomMove()
{
            // print(Time.time);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(foo);
            // print(Time.time);
            // Call your new coroutine here
            myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RandomMove());
}
```

this way you will have a coroutine variable for every iteration. If you need to stop the coroutine just say :

`StopCoroutine(myCoroutine);`

in your function at required time.This will allow you to stop a coroutine in middle before the end of countdown. Also at the end of coroutine it will start new coroutine with updated reference After finishing your task just call back again with

```
myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RandomMove());
```

Hope this resolves your problem. Yes you can do it with timer also with a boolean flag the same thing but I think using coroutine is much simpler.
.

Comment: For various reasons, I'd like to point out that it's better to store the `IEnumerator` reference than the `Coroutine` reference.

Comment: @Galandil what are the "various reasons" to store an `IEnumerator` reference instead?

Comment: @sonny Using `IEnumerator` is simpler to manage/read in the code, because you can assign the reference anywhere before the coroutine is started. Moreover, you can use all the methods and properties of an `IEnumerator`, even though this point in Unity is limited to `MoveNext()` for standard coroutines - you can however create classes which inherits from `IEnumerator`, and those can implement `Reset()` and `Current` (and if this is the case, all the code will read a lot better, instead of a mix of `Coroutine` and `IEnumerator` references).

Comment: Another thing is that, in the case of coroutines with arguments, you can have a single `StartCoroutine(IEnum reference)`, and have more than one reference assignments with different parameters before calling the coroutine: with `Coroutine` you need to start the coroutine with specific parameters every time.

Comment: Given that `MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine` specifies a `Coroutine` as the return type, for the purpose of calling `StopCoroutine` I would argue that storing the reference as a `Coroutine` is fine in simple cases, though I understand the downside of having a mix of `Coroutine` and `IEnumerator` references. Perhaps Unity's `StartCoroutine` method should have been designed to specify an `IEnumerator` as the return type instead? I appreciate your detailed response, and I can see how storing an `IEnumerator` reference instead could be a useful practice.

Comment: I was truly baffled too the first time I studied the matter. The `Coroutine` type reference can only be taken when starting a coroutine, and it's useful only for stopping that coroutine. On the other side, the `IEnumerator` type, as I said, it's useful not only for stopping a coroutine, but for all the rest that I explained. And I forgot to mention that you can make it `public`, so that means that you can set that reference even outside the class that actually starts the coroutine. Basically, I find `Coroutine` a truly useless type, since it adds nothing to `IEnumerator`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm it could something like this also . Just for my own .

```
void Start() {
StartCoroutine(RepeatingFunction());
}

IEnumerator RepeatingFunction () {
yield return new WaitForSeconds(repeatTime);

StartCoroutine( RepeatingFunction() );
}
```

As i understand the question. `InvokeRepeating()` is also a choice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you are each frame waiting for new assigned seconds?

Why don't you make the random before yielding the wait, and store the CustomYieldInstruction instead of yielding a new instance, since it disposes the one that was before, that creates memory problems. You won't notice that if you yield return a WaitForSeconds with a constant value, but maybe with a random one creates ambiguity and resets the timer (see this [**Unity's optimization page, on the Coroutine's section**](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/performance-optimization/optimizing-garbage-collection-unity-games)). A quick example:

```
public float foo;
public float min;
public float max;

void Awake()
{
    StartCoroutine(Countdown());
}

IEnumerator Countdown()
{
    while(true)
    {
        foo = Random.Range(min, max);
        WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(foo);
        yield return wait;
    }
}
```

Also, @ryeMoss's solution seems a good one, to stop and restart the coroutine if 'foo' changes.

Hope it helps.